# Is there an archive that summarizes each story of pulp-era magazines, issue by issue?

Tags: short-stories, pulp

The pulp magazines published in the 20s, 30s and 40s are a goldmine of stories and ideas that sadly are mostly unavailable to the contemporary readers, since only a handful of those stories have been chosen and happen to be published today.

The majority of the pulp stories instead have simply been forgotten despite their qualities: they simply haven't been lucky enough to be picked over the next decade or two by the precursors of today's influencers and so never had a chance to really shine after that first and only printing, almost a century ago.
And now they have been consigned to oblivion.

So I wonder: is there a web-based archive or database that not only lists the contents of each issue (there's a few of those already) but also adds a summary of the stories they included?
I haven't been able to find any but I'm also pretty poor at searching the web so I wouldn't be surprised if I missed them.

What I mean is not the elevator pitches that magazines like Amazing Stories and Weird Tales used to associate with the titles in their tables of contents but a somewhat longer abstract that summarizes the story and helps understand how the plot unfolds.
I would be very interested in such an archive.

Comment: If such a thing existed we would be all over it, and there would be a _lot_ fewer unanswered story-id questions around here. :)

Comment: As you know, images of most of those old pulps are freely available at archive.org. But it's summaries you're after. A few thousand stories from the decade starting in 1926 (year *Amazing Stories* was founded) are summarized in detail in in E. F. Bleiler's *Science-Fiction: The Gernsback Years*. A big heavy hardcover book, not a web thing, but I think it's all viewable at Google Books. Too bad there's nothing like that for later stuff, For older sci-fi there's Bleiler's *Science-Fiction: The Early Years* which covers almost every sci-fi story ever written from the beginning of time to 1926.

Comment: @DavidW - I didn't take this into consideration but you're right!

Comment: @user14111 - My question originates from those freely available files indeed: I love reading them whenever I can but often the stories they include aren't up to the elevator pitches, so you happen to read several half stories without really enjoying any. I've glanced at both of Bleiler's mammoths you cite and found them very helpful (if only I could have them always available) but limited: they only cover a limited spell of time and ignore Weird Tales (and other not-strictly science fiction magazines) completely.

Comment: Are you interested enough to _start_ such a project?

Comment: @ZabZonk Agreed. However, *SF: The Early Years* does include sci-fi from *Weirt Tales*, e.g. Hamilton's *Interstellar Patrol* stories, "When the Green Star Waned" by  Nictzin Dyalhis.

Comment: @DavidW - I've considered that but I've no tech knowledge to build and manage a website so I gave up.